# Access-Control-Allow-Headers not allowed in preflight even if I added it on server side

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cors, authorization

I am getting this error while calling APIs.

**Before marking as 'duplicate', please read this.**

My frontend is in ReactJs and I'm using `axios` for API requests, backend in Laravel (v5, old project). Each API gives this error: `Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I have already done the following,

- Added cors policy to backend server as middleware:

  ```
  class CORS {    
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next) { 
            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => '*',
                // I have tried 'Authorization' instead of '*' also
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ];
            if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
                // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
                return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
            }

            return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        }
   }
  ```

*Is there any other way to get rid of the CORS error or am I missing anything here?*

**Update**
Axios sample code as per requested:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
// const token = get auth token from cookie/store
  config.headers = {
    'Authorization': token ? token : ''
  };
  return config;
});
```

Axios request:

```
Axios.get(myUrl)
  .then((response) => {
      // do something
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     // show error
  });
```

Comment: not really sure that's why i'm commenting! but try specifically setting authorization as allow header. like `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ''authorization"`

Comment: @saeedghotb I tried that also, still same error

Comment: works fine in my laravel 6 project, just had to change Response::make to response(), can you also share axios request?

Comment: @AkashSarode please check updated question for axios code and I tried `response()` instead of `Response::make` but no luck.

Comment: does your request pass through CORS middleware? try OPTIONS request with postman.

Comment: @AkashSarode yes it pass through CORS middleware.